# SED/AWK/PERL(GNU userland) - how to substitute pattern A but not pattern B?

Tags: sed, perl, awk, gnu

First, I am using GNU userland so you can assume I use Bash, GNU coreutils...

I have a HTML and I want to change all

```
href="foobarz"
```

into

```
href=""
```

However, I don't want to change any line containing the word `css` (not case-sensitive)

```
'href="fooCsSbarz"'
```

should remain unchanged

I am currently using the command

```
$ cat foo.html | sed -e 's/href="[^"]*"/href=""/g' > bar.html
```

but it cannot retain those lines containing the word `css` (not case-sensitive)

Actually, any tool available in *nix is welcomed,
like sed, awk, perl...

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176026/whats-wrong-with-my-lookahead-regex-in-linux-sed).

You can use:

```
sed '/[Cc][Ss][Ss]/! s/href="[^"]*"/href=""/g' foo.html > bar.html
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That thread 's title is not 'grep-friendly'...